# Create method for foreign key relationships with Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

My models are like this:

```
class FirewallPolicy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    source_ip = models.ForeignKey(IP)
    destination_ip = models.ForeignKey(IP)
```

Now, in order to create a new Firewall Policy, there should already be an existing team, source_ip and destination_ip. My payload to create a new Firewall Policy is as follows:

```
{"name": "test-create-policy-911",
 "team": "avengers",
 "source_ip": "1.1.1.1",
 "destination_ip": "2.2.2.2",
}
```

My serializer to create a new Firewall Policy is as follows:

```
class FirewallPolicyCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    team = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    source_ip = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    destination_ip = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'team', 'source_ip', 'destination_ip']

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            Team.objects.get(name=data['team'])
            IP.objects.get(name=data['source_ip'])
            IP.objects.get(name=data['destination_ip'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Entities must exist before you can associate it with a Firewall Policy")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        team = Team.objects.get(name=validated_data['team'])
        source_ip = IP.objects.get(name=validated_data['source_ip'])
        destination_ip = IP.objects.get(name=validated_data['destination_ip'])
        policy  = Policy.objects.create(name=validated_data['name'], 
                                        team_id=team.id, 
                                        source_ip_id = source_ip.id, 
                                        destination_ip_id = destination_ip.id )
        return policy
```

I am not sure if this is the right way of adding foreign keys to a model as it seems too much work. Is there something I am missing where the serializer can automatically check all this and add the foreign keys ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you are doing much more work than you need to.

You should define your fields using [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to allow DRF to automatically populate them from a field on the related model. So:

```
class FirewallPolicyCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
    source_ip = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=IP.objects.all(), slug_field='source_ip')
    destination_ip = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=IP.objects.all(), slug_field='destination_ip')

    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'team', 'source_ip', 'destination_ip']
```

Now you shouldn't need to define `validate` or `create` at all, as DRF will do all the relevant validation and assignment.

(Note, you didn't need to redefine the `name` field either, as you're not changing anything from the underlying model field.)

Comment: How can one implement this solution inside a dictionary of serializer's `create()`?